# Read binary data (ieee-le) in Python

Tags: python, binary, ieee-754, bin

I'm trying to open a binary file in Python, for which in Matlab I'm using

`data = fread(file, [rows, cols], 'float','ieee-le')`

In Python I tried both

`data = open(file,'rb').read()` &

`data = np.fromfile(file, dtype=data_type, count=count)`

neither of which gave expected results (for data_type I tried all formats listed on the info page).

Just reading the data, the first 25 samples look like this:

> b'\xe4\xa0B\xbc\x99\x9e\x1f\xbd\xc3\x07P>m\xe0\x96=\x0c\xf6\x8a=\x90\x86\t>)

While searching for solutions I stumbled over Python's struct package, but as I know close to nothing about data formats I was not able to use it to solve the problem. Any help would therefore be highly appreciated...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In numpy, ieee-le float type is `'<f4'`, which reads "little endian floating point of 4 bytes".

Thus you can open your file using:

```
data = np.fromfile(filename, dtype='<f4', count=count)
```